# Show product.length when I have JSON / OBJ / JSON / OBJ / JSON

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object, nativescript

I have this JSON

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusMessage": "OK",
    "StatusDescription": [
        {
            "_id": "12123",
            "dateCreated": "2019-12-03T13:45:30.418Z",
            "pharmacy_id": "011E752345553380ABC13FFA163ECD15"
            "products": [
                {
                    "productID": "1",
                    "quantity": 3,
                    "product_name": "BETADINE",
                    "price": 10
                },
                {
                    "productID": "2",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "product_name": "EUCARBON",
                    "price": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "56233",
            "dateCreated": "2019-12-04T09:55:21.555Z",
            "pharmacy_id": "011E762345552280FBC13FFA163ECD10"
            "products": [
                {
                    "productID": "44",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "product_name": "BETADINE",
                    "price": 10
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this JOSN I want to get length of products. For example in this I have 2 pharmacy and 5 products. I want to show 5 in my shop cart.

So I get this JSON from API with this function:

```
  public cart: Shop[];
  cartlength: number;

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.shopservice.getShoppingCart().subscribe(
            cart => {
                this.cart = cart;
                this.cartlength = cart.length;
            },
            err => console.error('errorrrrrrr', err),
            () => console.log('error')
        );
    }
```

IN HTML:

```
<ActionItem ios.systemIcon="9" ios.position="left" android.position="actionBar"  [text]='cartlength'></ActionItem>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: No. In `this.cartlength = cart.length;` I get number 2. But I want to get number of product.

Comment: simply use cart.StatusDescription[0].products.length for getting the length of 1st products  if you want the total length of all products just use forEach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cart is the array containing all the pharmacies you could use reduce method to determine the total quantity of all products for each pharmacy.

```js
this.cartlength = this.cart.reduce((count, pharmacy) => {
    count += pharmacy.products.reduce((totalQty, product) => {
        return totalQty += product.quantity;
    }, 0)
    return count;
}, 0)
```

Comment: True, in that case he could just use another reduce for the products array in each pharmacy, edited answer accordingly.